# Laravel (or PHP/MySQL?) cuts float numbers after decimal point

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, floating-point

Maybe this is a more general MySQL or PHP question deriving from my lack of knowledge in those fields, but...

So I have an app on Laravel 5.4, Database is MySQL 5.7.17

I have a column in talbe, created via migration:

```
$table->float('operator_price', 9, 2)->nullable()->change();
```

*(this, according to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#migration-structure), should mean that column has type 'FLOAT' with 9 total digits and 2 after decimal point)*
[image]

When user enters 1000.25 in the form field and saves - it's saved as '1000.25',

But if user enters 10000.25 - it's saved as '10000.2'.

**So it cuts the last digit if the number is over 9999.**

What may be the reason and how can I fix it?

Thank you.

---

UPDATE: I've done SHOW COLUMNS FROM tours;

and it shows that column 'operator_price' has type 'float':

[image]

Comment: What about validation before store? `['amount' => 'max:9999']`

Comment: Have you made sure your migration was successful and the field is actually of type `float(8,2)`?

Comment: please check your phpmyadmin `operator_price` column type

Comment: @Sohel0415 - yes, it has type 'float'

Comment: @LeventeOtta, there is no such validation before store.

Comment: @SergejFomin is it like `decimal(8,2)`?

Comment: @Sohel0415, no, it's exactly 'float' (see the screenshot above)

Comment: please check its length/ values in phpmyadmin

Comment: @SergejFomin you should use decimal instead of float. I know that mysql does allow the syntax that you use, but the decimal data type is more suitable. Also, the data type in the pcture does not have any restrictions, so the truncation may happen when you display the value from the db.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually float/double is not as precise as decimal. For monetary data, the decimal type is recommended, so you should probably use:

```
$table->decimal('operator_price', 10, 2); // instead of float
```

Read [this](https://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/) for some detailed information and [float manual from MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html).

Comment: Precision is not the issue, and it is not correct to say that double is not as precise as decimal(10, 2). Double has a precision of one part in 4503599627370496 or better, but decimal(10, 2) is at best one part in 10000000000. The issue is that decimal is commensurate with the values used to store and represent currency. But it should be kept in mind that decimal fails in the same way double does when doing any calculations other than addition, subtraction, or multiplication by integers. *E.g.*, calculating the unit price of something sold three for a dollar cannot be done in decimal.

Comment: You forgot to mention the column name it should be like `$table->decimal('operator_price', 10, 2)`

Comment: Thanks, @GaneshGhalame, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel Migration [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations):

```
$table->float('amount', 8, 2);
```

FLOAT equivalent column with a precision (total digits) and scale (decimal digits).