# Doubles losing their decimal places in unit tests

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

So I am in the process of **upgrading an old Laravel project from 5.3 to 5.4** (plan on going to 5.8), but I've run into a problem with my unit tests in which doubles are losing their decimal places.

Here's an example of one such test (**yes my tests interact with a database**):

```
$this->user->message_score = 3.42;
$this->user->save();
echo $this->user->fresh()->message_score; // 3
```

The migration for the table:

```
$table->double('message_score')->nullable();
```

Whatever number I set, the decimal places are lost. **It isn't round up or down, 3.42 becomes 3, as does 3.99.**

**Tinker does not have the same issue.**

I assume I am missing something simple.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

So I ran a migration to update the `message_score` precision and I am running into the same problem. The length displayed in the database before running the migration was `(8,2)` and the migration I ran pushed it up to `(10,8)`. The migration is below:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE `users` MODIFY `message_score` DOUBLE(10,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0;');
```

Comment: Can you do some `var_dump`s periodically to see when it is getting set to an integer, and share any relevant code from `save()` or `fresh()`?

Comment: did you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516430/laravel-or-php-mysql-cuts-float-numbers-after-decimal-point and Laravel documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations [Available Column Types]

Comment: @zbee they're just the standard Laravel `save()` and `fresh()` methods. That being said, the decimal number is saved into the database with the decimal places using the `save()` method.

Comment: @Akam already taken a look at that answer and had no luck, same with the documentation. If you use `->double('message_score')` without specifying the precision, it would still allow decimal places, just not as many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the MYSQL connection, specifically setting `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to true.

**PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES** is what allows you to reuse parameters in a prepared statement, for example, you could just use `:id` instead of `:id1, :id2, :id3`.
When it is set to `true` on **PHP >= 7.2**, it causes all floats to be cast to an integer, therefore losing the precision. This is due to Laravel not supporting this PDO flag.

There are essentially two options:

Set **PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES** to false and then start uniquely naming parameters, like so `:id1, :id2, :id3`.

Or

Set your floats to strings, at which point they will keep their decimals place as Laravel will no longer see it as a float and cast it to an integer.

Here is the issue on GitHub if you want to read more into it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23850

Answer (score 1):

You should include precision in your migrations:

```php
$table->double('message_score', 8, 2)->nullable();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, an additional migration needs to be run that updates each table that has doubles, floats, etc.?

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I tried it and had no luck. Will add further details to the question.